# How long has a snapshot been running?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, snapshot

Assume I made a snapshot of a certain VM one week ago. Today I revert to that snapshot, I think this means the `delta.vmdk` gets deleted (e.g. everything *after* the snapshot is lost). I think this also means that a new delta is created, from that snapshot, starting from today, so I have a snapshot running from today (day 0) despite it was created 1 week ago.

How to check from vSphere Client how long has a snapshot actually been running?

Answer (score 0):

> Today I revert to that snapshot, I think this means the delta.vmdk gets deleted (e.g. everything after the snapshot is lost).

Yes.

> I think this also means that a new delta is created, from that snapshot, starting from today, so I have a snapshot running from today (day 0) despite it was created 1 week ago.

Yes - reverting to the snapshot takes the VM back to last week.

> How to check from vSphere Client how long has a snapshot actually been running?

*Manage snapshots* shows the time and date when the snapshot was created.

Comment: probably I didn't make myself clear. If now I revert to a snapshot created one week ago, the snapshot has been _running_ for 0 days, but the snapshot is _created_ one week ago. I'm looking for the running time.

Comment: I don't think you can see that anywhere and I fail to see where that is relevant - from the guest's POV the system has been running for more than one week with a blackout/gap between the snapshot and the revert.

Comment: From a SysAdmin POV having a snapshot running for one week or having a snapshot running for few hours (despite being created long time ago) is indeed relevant.

Comment: Hmm. Been a sysadmin for 25+ years, I still don't care about that...